# AJAX file 403's

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, 403-forbidden

Google webmaster tools shows a couple of 403 crawl errors (URL errors, access denied) for folders holding AJAX files on the ColdFusion server:
CFIDE/scripts/ajax/FCKeditor/
CFIDE/scripts/ajax

Will this affect our site's ranking on Google?

Answer (score 1):

This won't affect your rankings. That error message will tell Google to stop crawling those pages and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

A 403 response doesn't really tell Google to stop trying to index this page. It's the server refusing the request. Google will probably continue trying to access these pages as it's not a 404. As John said it won't affect your rankings.